# Linux TCP congestion control algorithm in NS2

Tags: networking, ns2, congestion-control

I am using NS2 and I have version 2.35 on my Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0. The default TCP congestion algorithm for my Ubuntu is CUBIC.

Which congestion control algorithm do they exactly use when I make Linux TCP agents in NS2?

At first, I thought they will be using CUBIC which is my Linux's default algorithm but running experiments with NS2's CUBIC agents and Linux agents I am getting completely different results so I am coming to this conclusion that Linux agents are not using CUBIC or at least they are using a modified version of it. Does anyone knows what exactly is the algorithm that Linux TCP agents use in NS2 version 2.35?

Comment: Exactly what are the differences in the results? Differences in results depend on queue behavior and size, bottleneck rate, host nic speed etc..

Comment: The difference in results totally depends on what aspect of the simulation result you are looking for. I can say that Linux and CUBIC in NS2 have different results in different aspects, not only one or 2.